# Trying to Integrate$ \iint xy\log|x-y|\, dy\,dx $

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Hello I am trying to integrate $$
I:=\int_{a}^{b}\int_{a}^{b}xy\log\left(\,\left\vert\,x - y\,\right\vert\,\right)
\,{\rm d}y\,{\rm d}x,\qquad 0 < a <b
$$
for $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$.  I added the bounds of integration to deal with any convergence problems as suggested. We can re-write this as
$$
I=\frac{1}{2}\int_a^b \int_a^b xy\log \left((x-y)^2\right)\, dy\,dx.
$$
From here we can re-write the log as
$$
\frac{1}{2}\int_a^b \int_a^b xy \left(\int\frac{2}{x-y}dx\right)dy\, dx.
$$
I am not sure how to approach this from here till end.  Thanks.

Comment: The convergence of this integral is not clear to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x,y\in[a,b]\:\:$it converges, otherwise it does not. For simplicity lets say double integral is taken over $[0,1]\times[0,1]$.It has log singularity which is not that bad and integral converges $$
\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}  xy\log|x-y|\, dy\,dx=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{y}xy\log(y-x)\,dx\,dy+\int_{0}^{1}\int_{y}^{1}xy\log(x-y)\,dx\,dy
$$
$$=\int_{0}^{1}y\int_{0}^{y}x\log(y-x)\,dx\,dy+\int_{0}^{1}y\int_{y}^{1}x\log(x-y)\,dx\,dy$$
$$=\int_{0}^{1}y\int_{0}^{y}(y-t)\log t\,dt\,dy+\int_{0}^{1}y\int_{0}^{1-y}(y+s)\log s\,ds\,dy$$
$$=\int_0^1y(\frac{1}{2}y^2\log y-\frac{3}{4}y^2)dy+\int_0^1y\big(\frac{1}{2}(1-y^2)\log(1- y)-\frac{1}{4}(1-y)(1+3y)\big)dy\approx -0.437.$$

Comment: Thanks, I should have been more clear I am interested in the integral from a to b.  It is nice to see it done over $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ but how about $[a,b]\times [a,b]$?  Thank you.

Comment: As they say integral has diagonal singularity and end points do not affect convergence( as long as integral is not taken over unbounded region).you can replace $[0,1]$ with $[a,b]$ and emulate the same method.

Comment: remember $dt=-dx$ and integral is taken from $y$ to $0$, taking that into account you get the first integral in 3rd line.

Comment: How come the result of the integral ends up being complex when I emulate this method using [a,b] instead of [0,1]?  The imaginary piece comes from the double integral over the variable s, which is given by:$$\int_a^b ydy\left( \frac{1}{4}(b-y)(-b-3y+2(b+y)\ln(b-y)  \right).$$This integral should be real but it gives me a complex result.  Does that mean that breaking up the integrals the way you did is not allowed because of the logarithmic divergence or?  The result of the integral should be real.  Thanks

Comment: I would double check the computations. we have a positive measure supported on a segment and real-valued integrand so there is no way that results in a complex number.

Comment: I fixed the problem, thank you sir.  there was an imaginary term in the result that cancelled with a logarithm term since the argument of the log was negative.  Mathematica didn't catch this.  Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

First notice the integrand is symmetric in $x$ and $y$, so it suffices to double the $y > x$ portion; that is
$$
I:=2\int_{a}^{b}\int_{x}^{b}xy\log\left(y - x \right)
\,{\rm d}y\,{\rm d}x,\qquad 0 < a <b$$
Change variables to $u = y - x$ and $v = y + x$. The triangle of integration rotates to another triangle and we get 
$${1 \over 4}\int_{0}^{b - a}\int_{ 2a + u }^{2b - u}{v - u \over 2}{v + u \over 2}\log\left(u \right)
\,{\rm d}v\,{\rm d}u,\qquad 0 < a <b$$
$$= {1 \over 16}\int_{0}^{b - a}\log\left(u \right)\int_{ 2a + u }^{2b - u}(v^2 - u^2)
\,{\rm d}v\,{\rm d}u,\qquad 0 < a <b$$
$$ = {1 \over 16}\int_{0}^{b - a}\log\left(u \right)(-{4 \over 3})(2 a^3 + 3 a^2 u - (b - u)^2 (2 b + u))) \,du$$
The integral rather sucks but it can be done in an elementary fashion through an integration by parts.

Comment: Thank you, sir.  I am curious, how did you get rid of the absolute value sign in the first line?  And how is$$
I:=\int_{a}^{b}\int_{x}^{b}xy\log\left(y - x \right)
\,{\rm d}y\,{\rm d}x+\int_{a}^{b}\int_{x}^{b}xy\log\left(y - x \right)
\,{\rm d}y\,{\rm d}x,\qquad 0 < a <b
$$
equivalent to the original integral over $[a,b]\times [a,b]$?  Also how did you notice that the region of integration is a triangle?   Your method is very clever to start off, but I do not get the beginning..Thanks for help.